# PassOptionsToPackage: natbib via svjour3

Tags: bibtex, natbib, package-options

In this MWE, I am unable to pass options to `natbib` via `svjour3`, which requires natbib. The commented alternative works fine, but has some drawbacks (e.g., the code in `svjour3` after `\RequirePackage{natbib}`, such as `bibfont`, is somehow not executed.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers}{natbib}

\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}
%\documentclass{svjour3}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{something, author = "someone"}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \cite{something}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here is `svjour3`: http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198.zip (via https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates).

Edit: I think my more concrete question is: why does `\PassOptionsToPackage` work for the local call to `\RequirePackage` but not for the one in the `svjour3` class?

Minimal answer (see accepted one for explanation):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers,sort&compress,...}{natbib}
\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}
\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
```

This switches to numerical citation style and honors requested options while maintaining all the layout code from `svjour3`.

Comment: If this is for publication, they will undo your customisations anyway. If not, why use a class which is designed to impose a set, standard format?

Comment: The journal in question uses numeric styles while the templates is for author-year styles. Hence, I have to "customize". However, I would like to maintain as much of the original layout as possible without introducing additional code in the document (which I agree, would probably be removed before printing). Unfortunately, `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` does undo some of the template's layouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited to reflect additional information provided by the OP.)

With the `svjour3` document class, you get authoryear-style citation call-outs if you select the class option `natbib`; cf. p. 4 of the user guide and the fourth argument of the `\bibpunct` directive.

Fortunately, it's straightforward to change the citation callout style: Rerun the `\bibpunct` directive but use "n" as the fourth argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[natbib]{svjour3}

% Important change: Set fourth argument to "n" (default is "a")
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{n}{}{,} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{something, 
       author = "FirstName MiddleName LastName", 
       title  = "A very long and tedious title that says absolutely nothing",
       journal= "Circularity Today",
       year= 5678,
       volume = 1,
       number = 2,
       pages  = "3-4",
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \cite{something}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example is functionally identical to the commented variant in the MWE from my original question, so there is little to learn. Your MWE discards the `bibfont` calls and some more. Basically, I want to be able to switch between author-year (for editing) and numeric styles (for publishing) while retaining all design choices the class makes to be check page limits.

You also wrote: "With this option set, the `natbib` package is loaded with the option `authoryear`." Where do you see that? I cannot find this option in my `svjour3.cls`.

Comment: @bers - I've updated the answer in light of the additional information you've provided. Note that the document class selects authoryear-style citation callouts if the `natbib` option is provided because the fourth argument of `\bibpunct` is set to `a`. It needs to be set to `n` for numeric-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't know that `bibpunct` can overrule the `numeric` option of `natbib`. This was the missing piece. I will update my question to include a minimal version of your answer!

Comment: Oh, you minimized it yourself in the meantime. Thanks again!