# Hyperref does not work in baposter

Tags: hyperref, baposter

Could someone help with the following sample code where the `href` does not really result in a hyperlink in resulting pdf when build with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter}

\title{Summary}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
{
 bgColorOne=white, 
 bgColorTwo=white,
}

{\bf\textsc{Bhagvad Geeta Summary}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title


\headerbox{Bhagvad Geeta Summary}{name=saar, column=1,span=2, row=0}{

Your world is a \href{http://www.google.com}{perception} based by your 
prejudices, shaped by your fears, fueled by your ignorance.
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can we find this `baposter.cls?`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter.cls

Comment: I think that the box juggling done by the class prevents links to appear.

Comment: This is a known issue: https://code.google.com/archive/p/baposter/issues/9. `\url` from the `url` package does work, but of course it is not an `\href` replacement since it will only set the url as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 4):

The font scaling done by `baposter`, through the class option `fontscale`, results in misplacing the links. With certain page size and `fontscale` combinations, it can be shown that the links are indeed produced, and they are active, but they are not associated with the linked item. Setting paper size to `a0paper` and `fontscale=0.9` demonstrates this result - that is, the links are produced, but they are misplaced.

The solution here is to set the class option, `fontscale=1.0`. This necessitates setting all the font sizes manually in the `posterbox` environment. This is because setting `fontscale=1.0`, together with a large paper size, results in text that is too small for a large poster.

The MWE includes several tests that demonstrate use of the `posterbox` keys, `textfont` for setting the size of the `posterbox` text and `headerfont` for setting the size of the `posterbox` header content. These keys can be used globally for all `posterboxes`, as well as for individual `posterboxes`.

It is also possible to use the `\fontsize{fontsize}{baselineskip}\selectfont` syntax inside a `posterbox` to make the text larger.

The MWE tests links created with `\href`, `\url` and `\autocite`. The output shows the links correctly associated with the linked text.

There is further commentary in the MWE to explain what it does.

I did encounter one thing I don't understand (well, there are lots of things I don't understand yet in `LaTeX`), but when I used the `\fontsize{fontsize}{baselineskip}\selectfont` syntax, the baselineskip doesn't appear to be correct inside a `posterbox`, unless I put the text in a `parbox`.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=1.0]{baposter}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{helvet}    %scaleable, sans serif font
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    citebordercolor=red,
    urlbordercolor=orange,
    pdfborder=0 0 5}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault} % Default font is sans serif

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240950. Thanks Mico.
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{something,
       author = "FirstName MiddleName LastName",
       title  = "A very long and tedious title that says absolutely nothing",
       journal= "Circularity Today",
       year= 5678,
       volume = 1,
       number = 2,
       pages  = "3-4",
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
columns=2,
background=none,
headerborder=closed,
borderColor=green,
textborder=rectangle,
headershade=plain,
headerColorOne=green!40!white,
boxColorOne=green!10!white,
textfont=\huge, % font definition for body of posterbox
headerfont=\Huge\scshape, % font definition for header of posterbox
}
{} % Logo left
{\fontsize{150}{150}\selectfont\bfseries\textsc{Summary}} % Poster title
{} % Authors
{} % Logo right
\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,column=0,span=1,row=0]{Box 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
\end{posterbox}

% Use the textfont or headerfont keys to adjust the font size
\begin{posterbox}[name=box2,column=0,span=1,below=box1,headerfont=\large,textfont=\normalfont]{Box 2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
\end{posterbox}

% Or use \fontsize{fontsize}{baseline}\selectfont
\begin{posterbox}[name=box3,column=0,span=1,below=box2]{Box 3}
\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
\end{posterbox}

% Larger font
\begin{posterbox}[name=box4,column=0,span=1,below=box3]{Box 4}
\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
\end{posterbox}

% Baseline skip doesn't look correct. Add a parbox.
\begin{posterbox}[name=box5,column=0,span=1,below=box4]{Box 5}
\parbox{\boxwidth-1cm}{%
\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit. 
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
}
\end{posterbox}

% Even larger
\begin{posterbox}[name=box6,column=0,span=1,below=box5]{Box 6}
\parbox{\boxwidth-1cm}{%
\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
}
\end{posterbox}

% Look at the baseline again without parbox. Don't know what's happening here.
\begin{posterbox}[name=box7,column=0,span=1,below=box6]{Box 7}
\fontsize{80}{120}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \href{http://www.google.com}{consectetur} adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque hendrerit felis vitae dolor tempus posuere. Morbi et justo dapibus, dictum.
\end{posterbox}

% A box with a citation
\begin{posterbox}[name=box8,column=1,span=1,row=0]{Box 8}
\parbox{\boxwidth-1cm}{%
\fontsize{80}{120}\selectfont
This is a citation: \autocite{something}

This is a url: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
}
\end{posterbox}

% A box with a bibliography that links to the citation
\begin{posterbox}[name=box9,column=1,span=1,aligned=box6,bottomaligned=box7]{References} % Note: aligned key is undocumented
\parbox{\boxwidth-1cm}{%
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont} % or any other  appropriate font command
\printbibliography[heading=none]
}
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]